# Facebook API find out if a page I have permission to advertise on is published and not restricted

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have managed to get permission to create adverts for customer's pages through the API, but some of the pages they choose to advertise on that we list from their account are either not published or restricted (restricted from advertising). I have looked everywhere on Facebook to find out how to check (and what permissions are required) whether a page is published and not restricted from advertising. I want to know whether they are restricted so I don 't list them as possible pages to advertise to.

Can someone help me with what call to the API to make to get this information and what permissions will be required for this?

Comment: Whether it is published or not, you can easily find out via the `is_published` field. Whether any age or region restrictions apply, I don't see anything in the docs regarding that.

Comment: Thank you yes I have now found the <page_id>?fields=is_published end point. Which seems to work!